# Excel - Tally up cells with value of [days], [hrs], [min], cell value example: 1 day, 1 hr, 10 min

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with the following values which I need to tally up (just an example of the real world application)

```
23 hr, 0 min.
1 day, 1 hr, 10 min
7 day, 8 hr, 10 min
18 minutes.
0 minutes.
```

Is it possible to have a formula which will add this up to, in this case

```
9 day, 8 hr, 38 min
```

If it is less than 1 day, it will not show x Days but will only show e.g. 5 hr, 39 min.
If it is less than 1 hour, it will not show x Hours, but will only show e.g. 20 min.

Comment: Are the values stored as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way, using additional columns to make the formulas much simpler:

Assuming text values are in column A rows 1-5:

Add formula to B1 and drag down:

```
=(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("day","000"&A1)-5,2)),0))+(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("hr",A1)-3,3)),0)/24)+(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("min",A1)-3,3)),0)/3600)
```

Add following formulas for days/hours/minute columns at the end (B6-B9)

```
=SUM(B1:B5)
=ROUNDDOWN(B6,0)
=MOD(B6,1)
=MOD(B6,1/60)
```

Then add the formula to display:

```
=IF(B7>0,TEXT(B7,"#")&" day"&IF(B7>1,"s "," "),"")&IF(B8>0,TEXT(B8*24,"#")&" hour"&IF(B8*24>1,"s "," "),"")&IF(B9>0,TEXT(B9*3600,"#")&" minute"&IF(B9*3600>1,"s "," "),"")
```